# How does windows encode the SAM file

Tags: python-3.x, security, hash, encoding, passwords

I am looking to a read the content of the SAM file to access the cryptographic hash of each user's password

obviously this is encoded but my question is how.

from what i have read, when the system is booted SYSKEY encrypts the SAM files to restrict access to these hashes. But then from other locations this is refered to 
as something enableable

Others refer to the encoding as being Binary and Hex

All I am looking for is what is done to encode these hashes in a SAM file on a windows 10 system.

**edit**

I'm still looking for an answer to this question, thanks.

Comment: You could have a look at open source tools that extract hashes from the SAM hive like [samdump2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ophcrack/files/samdump2/). You can have a look at the source and see what's going on, it's not very complex. Also have a look at [this](https://github.com/msuhanov/regf/blob/master/Windows%20registry%20file%20format%20specification.md).

Comment: Thank you, the reading was very informative. Unfortunately every version of Samdump, PWdump, ophcrack e.g. (any program that offers the ability to extract hashes) are riddled with Trojans/malware e.g. and I don't seem to be able to find any open source for this process. Do you know of a working link  providing open source code, or any further reading on specifically extracting these hashes using python.

Comment: If you download samdump2-3.0.0.tar.bz2 from the samdump2 link above, that's the source code. Sorry for the confusion, I meant that one not the binary. :)

Comment: I have examined the files, thank you. However i do believe this is beyond my abilities at the moment :) maybe you could point me in the direction of some reading specifically about the encoding of the SAM file? This really is something i would like to get my head around